# Java generics incompatible types error for type parameter inside method

Tags: java, generics

```
class G<I extends Integer, N extends Number>{

    /*
     * using the type parameter used at the class level also for the method below.
     * */
    public void myMethod(I i, N n){
        List<I> listI = new ArrayList<>();
        List<? extends Number> listN = listI;
        List<N> listN2 = listI;//error
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why line 3 in myMethod says **incompatible types**?
N is defined as "`N extends Number`" in the class declaration. So how are

`List<? extends Number> listN = listI;` and

```
List<N> listN2 = listI;
```

Are different here?

Comment: If your code compiled, you would be able to add any Number (a Double, a Long, a Byte) to listI, which is a List<Integer>. That's precisely what generics are designed to prevent.

Comment: ? means any type that extends number but N mean a specific type that extends Number but you haven't given that type and you can't create a list with a specific type that is unknown

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the comment but I don't think that is an answer to my question here. My question is basically why List<? extends Number> listN = listI; works but List<N extends Number> listN2 = listI; does not work. Maybe Joakim Danielson has a better understanding of the question. What do you think about his answer?

Comment: Because List<? extends Number> means: a list of an unknown type, which extends Number. You can't add anything to such a List. List<N> means: a list of type N. You can add any instance of N to such a List. Since the type of listN is unknown, there is no way to know that its type is N. And assigning it to a variable of type List<N> is thus not correct.

Comment: @JBNizet I can assign listI to listN but can't assign which is defined as a list of ? extends Number. I CANT assign listI to listN2 which is defined as a list of N extends Number. Why does the assignment work for a list of "ANY type that extends Number" but not for a list of "A type that extends Number"?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I can assign listI to listN but can't assign which is defined as a list of ? extends Number. I CANT assign listI to listN2 which is defined as a list of N extends Number. Why does the assignment work for a list of "UNKNOWN type that extends Number" but not for a list of "A type that extends Number"?

Comment: ? extends Number doesn't mean "any type that extends Number". It means "a very specific type that extends Number, but which is unknown". Maybe it's Integer. Maybe it's Double. Maybe it's Byte. We don't know. And since we don't know, we don't know if this type is N, and we can't add anything to that list.

Comment: @JBNizet ok let's fix my question as "a specific type which is unknown". question still stands.

Comment: I is a specific type that extends Integer. Integer extends Number. So I is a specific type that extends Number. So a List<I> is a list of a specific type which extends Number. When you assign it to a List<? extends Number>, you don't  break anything. It's just that you don't know what the specific type is anymore. When you assign a List<? extends Number> to a List<N>, however, you make the assumption that the unknow type (which in this case is Integer) is the type N (which could be Integer, but also Double or Long). So that's not safe: you could end up adding Double or Long to a List<Integer>

Comment: @JBNizet Actually, I am not assigning List<? extends Number> to a List<N> but assigning List<I> to List<N>. So the problem here is that compiler thinks N and I both extend Number but they are different types? And hence it will be like trying to put apples in an orange basket, right? Think I understand now. Cheers!

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the confusion. Read my very first comment, and the duplicate question I linked to. The compiler thinks they are different types because they **are** different types. One is named I, and is an Integer. one is named N, and can be any type that is or extends Number (so Number, Integer, Double, Long, etc.) Suppose N is Long. Long and Integer aren't the same type, are they? And you really don't want to be able to add a Long to a List<Integer>.